# Center alignment of a entry in a row

Tags: tables

I created a table using the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} p{7cm}}

Parameter& Value & Remark      \\  
\hline \hline
     $\alpha$            & $1[-]$   & Reference angle.          \\
    \hline
     $\alpha_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$       & $\beta_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$     &Inflow angle.  \\
    \hline
    $\delta$      & $\num{0.5894}c = \SI{0.59475}{\mm}$  $\num{9.87}  / c_{ax} = \num{5.874}$    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$-$}           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The output of which is:
[image]

I would like to center align only the text in the fourth row and third column vertically i.e., `-`. I want other entries in the third column to be left aligned.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to center all entries in the last row or do you just want to vertically center the `-`? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis Just the `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load `multirow` and count the maximum number of lines in the other cells:

```
\begin{tabular}{c >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.8cm} p{7cm}}
Parameter& Value & Remark \\
\hline \hline
     $\alpha$ & $1[-]$ & Reference angle. \\
    \hline
     $\alpha_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$ & $\beta_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$ &Inflow angle. \\
    \hline
    $\delta$ & $\num{0.5894}c = \SI{0.59475}{\mm}$ $\num{9.87} / c_{ax} = \num{5.874}$ & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering $-$} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

*Unrelated*: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` is useless in a `c` column.

[image]

Comment: Bernard am I supposed to use any package to use the command `\multirow{2}{=}{\centering $-$}` ? I am not getting the desired output. I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO4x6.jpg)

Comment: @Giri: add the `multirow` package in order to use the `\multirow` command. Without the `multirow` package, you should recieve an error message. As soon as you get an error message, don't look at the output.

Comment: Yes, I said so (load `\multirow`)